# Barcode types supported by jasonette vision api

Tags: jasonette

I have a question regarding the $vision.scan action for scanning barcodes and hope someone could help me with that. Do we need to provide any particular option to be able to scan EAN 13 or EAN 8 barcodes? The example :  (https://jasonbase.com/things/PMj7) is able to scan QR codes without any issues but isn't able to scan any other type of barcode. The gif in the $vision.scan documentation shows that a number of different types of barcodes are being scanned. Could it be a version issue? I'm using a Oneplus 5, running Android  8.1.0. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to change some code in Android Studio.

In App > Java > com.jasonette.seed > Service > Vision > JasonVisionService.java

Find setBarcodeFormats.

```
        detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context)
             // .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.EAN_13 | Barcode.EAN_8)
                .build();
```

In the above example I've commented out the QR_CODE format and instead added my own to scan EAN_8 and EAN_13.
More info:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector.Builder